# How to know the file size information and download progress indication in iterm2 terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2, osx-yosemite

Sometime when I download any file from terminal there is no indication of how small or big file and no progress bar to know the progress.

[image]

Is there a way to get these features?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with iterm and everything to do with the program you're using to download the file. It's up to you to find the correct arguments/flags in each case, or an alternative tool with support for this. Often there might be a --verbose option or similar.

Remember to try to view iterm as just the window holding the terminal, because that's what it is. Everything else is up to your shell and your installed programs.